# Öresundståg and the ID / border controls

Tags: customs-and-immigration, trains, sweden, denmark

I will be travelling by Öresundståg from Copenhagen airport to Helsingborg on Friday 1 June and then back again from Helsingborg to Copenhagen airport on Sunday 3 June.

I'm very worried about these ID / border controls causing delays on the train. From what I have seen on the Internet, people can be forced off the train to undergo ID / border controls and these controls can cause a delay where the train skips Copenhagen airport and stops at Tårnby, and passengers have to take another train back to the airport.

This won't be so much a problem when going to Helsingborg as I can arrive a few hours later, but when coming back it's important that I don't miss my flight. The train is supposed to come to the airport three and a half hours before my flight leaves. I am worried that if the train skips the airport and I have to take another train back I'll miss my flight.

Are these controls still being done? From what I have seen from Öresundståg's website, they are done only when going to Sweden, when coming back to Denmark there are no controls any more. Does that mean the train will go on schedule?

I've found plenty of articles on the Internet about Öresundståg skipping the airport but these are from 2016. That was two years ago. Does this mean that now that there apparently are no controls being done when coming back to Denmark, the trains stop at the airport as normal?

I'm not worried about the controls as such, as I'm a Nordic citizen and have a valid passport. What I'm worried about is that they might cause me to miss my train connections and most importantly, miss my flight back home.

Comment: I never had troubles with controls, but buying train tickets can take some extra time. Lines at the ticket machines in Copenhagen airport can be very long and the machines in Sweden are not very reliable and often have trouble processing credit card payments. Consider pre-buying at https://www.sj.se/en/home.html#/ or get the app (if you have right nationality)

Comment: One more thing: last year, there was construction happening and the trains were very UNRELIABLE. Massive delays and frequency cancellations were quite common. Recommendation at the time was to add at least two hours to your schedule if you need to "make the flight". Example: I was on non-stop from Almhult to CPH and kicked off at Malmo due to an "issue" with the train. Next train got cancelled, next train was so full that you couldn't get on, and so I ended up on train #4. Still made it but I really needed the buffer.

Comment: Not sure about the current state. Here is a Nov update: https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g189806-i232-k11000377-A_warning_for_tourists_in_Sweden_avoid_Oresundstag_trains-Sweden.html

Comment: The Öresundståg site lists all planned constructions for 2018. There doesn't seem to be any planned construction on the route I'm taking for 1 to 3 June.
There is some construction in Hässleholm for 1 to 3 June but that's not even in the direction I'm going.
Does this mean I'll avoid the same incident as Hilmar mentioned above?

Comment: Can anyone else give their opinion on Hilmar's comment above? How common is such a situation?

The train skipping CPH airport and stopping at Tårnby instead is no problem if I'm able to catch the train back in about half an hour. But if all the trains back are full or cancelled then I'm out of luck.

According to this site: https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Kastrup/T%C3%A5rnby I could also take a taxi from Tårnby station to the airport or simply walk the entire way. But how easy is it to get a taxi, or is there a safe footway along the entire way?

Comment: Your trip is long behind you know, but for the benefit of anyone else who may happen to come across this: if there are no other significant delays, skipping the airport and catching the next train from Tårnby back to it will not delay you more than perhaps 20 minutes at the very most. If you have factored in three and a half hours from arriving at the airport until your flight leaves, you are perfectly fine. Unless you hit extreme peak hour, it’s very unlikely that getting from the train to the gate will take you more than one hour, including check-in, security, and passport control.

Answer (score 6):

Going to Sweden, the train will stop at Hyllie, the first Swedish station, whereby our police may come onboard, walk through the train and check passports/IDs. Usually they won't even check your document in detail; I myself only hold up my ID card, they check for half a second that I have something, and then move on.

Going back to Denmark there are no checks whatsoever; there never were.

Comment: I've made this trip a few times last year. While the train does stop in Hyllie, I've never seen an actual control happening. It typically just stays there for a bit and then continues without police coming on board.

Comment: @Hilmar Oh yes, they're indeed only spot checks, unlike at the bridge

Answer (score 6):

It turned out that there was no problem whatsoever. The trains were on time in both directions.
When going to Sweden I had to undergo passport control. The Swedish police came on board the train and asked for my passport. I showed it to them and everything was OK.
When coming back to Denmark to catch my flight back home I didn't even have to undergo passport control, it was just a normal train ride. I actually fell asleep on the train and thus had to skip photographing the Öresund bridge.

Comment: You can't see much of the bridge from the train anyway -- only girders going past on both sides of the train.